# MS WORD triplicate each sentence in paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have long documents spanning hundreds of pages with tables and images. The tables contain vertically and horizontally merged cells.
I triplicate each sentence in a paragraph for easier mastery when reading, especially using the Read Aloud feature on MS Word. I came up with the following VBA code for triplicating. It works but takes so long especially for long documents
Any suggestions on how I can speed things up?
Or even a different code that can work even in the vertically merged cell tables faster

```
Sub TriplicateSentencesin_each_Paragraph()
'Each paragraph must have a period at the end
'First I replace each paragraph period with 3 periods to allow 
'for the loop through 'paragraphs to end of doc

Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
.Text = ".^p"
.Replacement.Text = "...^p"
.Execute REPLACE:=wdReplaceAll
End With

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

Dim IsFound As Boolean
IsFound = True

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "...^p"
    .Replacement.Text = ".^p"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

While IsFound

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine

Selection.Find.Execute REPLACE:=wdReplaceOne


Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdParagraph, count:=1

Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdSentence, count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
Selection.Copy

Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
                
                
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=3
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine

IsFound = Selection.Find.Execute
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Turning off screen updating is the easiest way to speed up a macro. Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described, all you need is a single *wildcard* Find/Replace (not even a macro), where:

```
Find = [!^13]@[.\!\?]
Replace = ^& ^& ^&
```

Or, as a macro:

```
Sub Triplicates()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[!^13]@[.\!\?]"
    .Replacement.Text = "^& ^& ^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note than sentences ending in ? and ! are also processed.

Comment: Only issue is the code messes up sentences with decimal points or words such as e.g or i.e

Comment: The fundamental issue you will have with any approach is that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following: *Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts.* For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.